# Mootools Request getting "501 Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')" response

Tags: python, http, mootools, cors

I have this mootools request:

```
new Request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/list',
    method: 'get',
}).send();
```

and a small python server that handles it with this:

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import subprocess

class HttpHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/list':
            self.list()
        else:
            self._404()

    def list(self):
        self.response200()
        res = "some string"

        self.wfile.write(res)

    def _404(self):
        self.response404()
        self.wfile.write("404\n")

    def response200(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Request, X-Requested-With')
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

    def response404(self):
        self.send_response(404)
        self.send_header('Content-type', 'application/json')
        self.end_headers()

def main():
    try:
        server = HTTPServer(('', 8080), HttpHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.socket.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

When I attempt to make this request, I get these errors:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/ 501 (Unsupported method ('OPTIONS'))
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

I'm not sure what's going on. Can someone help me out??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

exactly as the response string tells you: `OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/ 501 (Unsupported method ('OPTIONS'))`

When javascript attempts to request a resource from another origin, modern browsers first ask the other server, the target, if it is ok to make that request from another origin, that's exactly what the `Access-Control*` headers do.  but this request does *not* happen in a normal `GET`, since that would be actually performing the request anyway, and instead use the `OPTIONS` method, which exists for the sole reason to inform clients what they are allowed to do, without actually doing it.

So, you need a `do_OPTIONS` method, which might look something like:

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    if self.path in ('*', '/list'):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Allow', 'GET, OPTIONS')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Request, X-Requested-With')
    else:
        self.send_response(404)
    self.send_header('Content-Length', '0')
    self.end_headers()
```