# CORS with python baseHTTPserver 501 (Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')) in chrome

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, cors, webiopi

Hi I need some help with base authentification while a ajax get/post request to a python baseHTTPserver.

I was able to change some lines of code in the python script for sending CORS headers. It works fine in modern browsers when I disable http base authentification.

If authentification is enabled i get a 501 (Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')) error (i chrome).

I spend hours with finding a solution an now i think iam on a good way. As i read in the topics below the HTTPRequestHandler might cause the problem but my pyton skills are not good enough to solve the problem.

If found some post about this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470414/strange-jquery-error-code-501-message-unsupported-method-options) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10157581/mootools-request-getting-501-unsupported-method-options-response) but iam not able to get it running with the script i have. Can someone help me to get it running?

Any help or ideas are would be highly appreciated.

```
    #   Copyright 2012-2013 Eric Ptak - trouch.com
    #
    #   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    #   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    #   You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    #   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    #   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    #   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    #   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    #   limitations under the License.

    import os
    import threading
    import re
    import codecs
    import mimetypes as mime
    import logging

    from webiopi.utils import *

    if PYTHON_MAJOR >= 3:
        import http.server as BaseHTTPServer
    else:
        import BaseHTTPServer

    try :
        import _webiopi.GPIO as GPIO
    except:
        pass

    WEBIOPI_DOCROOT = "/usr/share/webiopi/htdocs"

    class HTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer, threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, host, port, handler, context, docroot, index, auth=None):
            BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, ("", port), HTTPHandler)
            threading.Thread.__init__(self, name="HTTPThread")
            self.host = host
            self.port = port

            if context:
                self.context = context
                if not self.context.startswith("/"):
                    self.context = "/" + self.context
                if not self.context.endswith("/"):
                    self.context += "/"
            else:
                self.context = "/"

            self.docroot = docroot

            if index:
                self.index = index
            else:
                self.index = "index.html"

            self.handler = handler
            self.auth = auth

            self.running = True
            self.start()

        def get_request(self):
            sock, addr = self.socket.accept()
            sock.settimeout(10.0)
            return (sock, addr)

        def run(self):
            info("HTTP Server binded on http://%s:%s%s" % (self.host, self.port, self.context))
            try:
                self.serve_forever()
            except Exception as e:
                if self.running == True:
                    exception(e)
            info("HTTP Server stopped")

        def stop(self):
            self.running = False
            self.server_close()

    class HTTPHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        logger = logging.getLogger("HTTP")

        def log_message(self, fmt, *args):
            self.logger.debug(fmt % args)

        def log_error(self, fmt, *args):
            pass

        def version_string(self):
            return VERSION_STRING

        def checkAuthentication(self):
            if self.server.auth == None or len(self.server.auth) == 0:
                return True

            authHeader = self.headers.get('Authorization')
            if authHeader == None:
                return False

            if not authHeader.startswith("Basic "):
                return False

            auth = authHeader.replace("Basic ", "")
            if PYTHON_MAJOR >= 3:
                auth_hash = encrypt(auth.encode())
            else:
                auth_hash = encrypt(auth)

            if auth_hash == self.server.auth:
                return True
            return False

        def requestAuthentication(self):
            self.send_response(401)
            self.send_header("WWW-Authenticate", 'Basic realm="webiopi"')
            self.end_headers();

        def sendResponse(self, code, body=None, type="text/plain"):
            if code >= 400:
                if body != None:
                    self.send_error(code, body)
                else:
                    self.send_error(code)
            else:
                self.send_response(code)
                self.send_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET")
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", " X-Custom-Header")
                if body != None:
                    self.send_header("Content-Type", type);
                    self.end_headers();
                    self.wfile.write(body.encode())

        def findFile(self, filepath):
            if os.path.exists(filepath):
                if os.path.isdir(filepath):
                    filepath += "/" + self.server.index
                    if os.path.exists(filepath):
                        return filepath
                else:
                    return filepath
            return None


        def serveFile(self, relativePath):
            if self.server.docroot != None:
                path = self.findFile(self.server.docroot + "/" + relativePath)
                if path == None:
                    path = self.findFile("./" + relativePath)

            else:
                path = self.findFile("./" + relativePath)                
                if path == None:
                    path = self.findFile(WEBIOPI_DOCROOT + "/" + relativePath)

            if path == None and (relativePath.startswith("webiopi.") or relativePath.startswith("jquery")):
                path = self.findFile(WEBIOPI_DOCROOT + "/" + relativePath)

            if path == None:
                return self.sendResponse(404, "Not Found")

            realPath = os.path.realpath(path)

            if realPath.endswith(".py"):
                return self.sendResponse(403, "Not Authorized")

            if not (realPath.startswith(os.getcwd()) 
                    or (self.server.docroot and realPath.startswith(self.server.docroot))
                    or realPath.startswith(WEBIOPI_DOCROOT)):
                return self.sendResponse(403, "Not Authorized")

            (type, encoding) = mime.guess_type(path)
            f = codecs.open(path, encoding=encoding)
            data = f.read()
            f.close()
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-Type", type);
            self.send_header("Content-Length", os.path.getsize(realPath))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(data)

        def processRequest(self):
            self.request.settimeout(None)
            if not self.checkAuthentication():
                return self.requestAuthentication()

            request = self.path.replace(self.server.context, "/").split('?')
            relativePath = request[0]
            if relativePath[0] == "/":
                relativePath = relativePath[1:]

            if relativePath == "webiopi" or relativePath == "webiopi/":
                self.send_response(301)
                self.send_header("Location", "/")
                self.end_headers()
                return

            params = {}
            if len(request) > 1:
                for s in request[1].split('&'):
                    if s.find('=') > 0:
                        (name, value) = s.split('=')
                        params[name] = value
                    else:
                        params[s] = None

            compact = False
            if 'compact' in params:
                compact = str2bool(params['compact'])

            try:
                result = (None, None, None)
                if self.command == "GET":
                    result = self.server.handler.do_GET(relativePath, compact)
                elif self.command == "POST":
                    length = 0
                    length_header = 'content-length'
                    if length_header in self.headers:
                        length = int(self.headers[length_header])
                    result = self.server.handler.do_POST(relativePath, self.rfile.read(length), compact)
                else:
                    result = (405, None, None)

                (code, body, type) = result

                if code > 0:
                    self.sendResponse(code, body, type)
                else:
                    if self.command == "GET":
                        self.serveFile(relativePath)
                    else:
                        self.sendResponse(404)

            except (GPIO.InvalidDirectionException, GPIO.InvalidChannelException, GPIO.SetupException) as e:
                self.sendResponse(403, "%s" % e)
            except ValueError as e:
                self.sendResponse(403, "%s" % e)
            except Exception as e:
                self.sendResponse(500)
                raise e

        def do_GET(self):
            self.processRequest()

        def do_POST(self):
            self.processRequest()
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The client should issue two requests, first one OPTIONS and then the GET request. The solution presented is not optimal, since we are answering the OPTIONS request with contents.

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
            self.sendResponse(200)
            self.processRequest() # not good!
```

We should answer the OPTIONS request properly. If we do so, the client will issue the GET request after receiving a proper answer.

I was getting the 501 Unsupported method ('OPTIONS')) caused by CORS and by requesting the "Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8".

To solve the error, I enabled CORS in do_OPTIONS and enabled clients to request a specific content type.

My solution:

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    self.send_response(200, "ok")
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS')
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With")
    self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
    self.end_headers()

 def do_GET(self):
    self.processRequest()
```

Answer (score 3):

**Got it working:**

Ajax will send a `OPTIONS` request to the server, so you have to add a  `do_options` method to `BaseHTTPRequestHandler` without authentification (send response code 200).

After that you can call the function for processing the request as usual.

**Here is my solution (checked in Safari 6.x, Firefox 20, Chrome26 on OS X):**

```
def do_OPTIONS(self):
    self.sendResponse(200)
    self.processRequest()
```

The second thing you have to change is that you have to add a response header in the `processRequest` function. Add Access-Control-Allow-Headers:Authorization for example like `self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")`for allowing ajax to send the base authentification token.

The working script:

```
        #   Copyright 2012-2013 Eric Ptak - trouch.com
    #
    #   Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    #   you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    #   You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    #   Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    #   distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    #   WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    #   See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    #   limitations under the License.

    import os
    import threading
    import re
    import codecs
    import mimetypes as mime
    import logging

    from webiopi.utils import *

    if PYTHON_MAJOR >= 3:
        import http.server as BaseHTTPServer
    else:
        import BaseHTTPServer

    try :
        import _webiopi.GPIO as GPIO
    except:
        pass

    WEBIOPI_DOCROOT = "/usr/share/webiopi/htdocs"

    class HTTPServer(BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer, threading.Thread):
        def __init__(self, host, port, handler, context, docroot, index, auth=None):
            BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer.__init__(self, ("", port), HTTPHandler)
            threading.Thread.__init__(self, name="HTTPThread")
            self.host = host
            self.port = port

            if context:
                self.context = context
                if not self.context.startswith("/"):
                    self.context = "/" + self.context
                if not self.context.endswith("/"):
                    self.context += "/"
            else:
                self.context = "/"

            self.docroot = docroot

            if index:
                self.index = index
            else:
                self.index = "index.html"

            self.handler = handler
            self.auth = auth

            self.running = True
            self.start()

        def get_request(self):
            sock, addr = self.socket.accept()
            sock.settimeout(10.0)
            return (sock, addr)

        def run(self):
            info("HTTP Server binded on http://%s:%s%s" % (self.host, self.port, self.context))
            try:
                self.serve_forever()
            except Exception as e:
                if self.running == True:
                    exception(e)
            info("HTTP Server stopped")

        def stop(self):
            self.running = False
            self.server_close()

    class HTTPHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
        logger = logging.getLogger("HTTP")

        def log_message(self, fmt, *args):
            self.logger.debug(fmt % args)

        def log_error(self, fmt, *args):
            pass

        def version_string(self):
            return VERSION_STRING

        def checkAuthentication(self):
            if self.server.auth == None or len(self.server.auth) == 0:
                return True

            authHeader = self.headers.get('Authorization')
            if authHeader == None:
                return False

            if not authHeader.startswith("Basic "):
                return False

            auth = authHeader.replace("Basic ", "")
            if PYTHON_MAJOR >= 3:
                auth_hash = encrypt(auth.encode())
            else:
                auth_hash = encrypt(auth)

            if auth_hash == self.server.auth:
                return True
            return False

        def requestAuthentication(self):
            self.send_response(401)
            self.send_header("WWW-Authenticate", 'Basic realm="webiopi"')
            self.end_headers();

        def sendResponse(self, code, body=None, type="text/plain"):
            if code >= 400:
                if body != None:
                    self.send_error(code, body)
                else:
                    self.send_error(code)
            else:
                self.send_response(code)
                self.send_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS")
                self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")
                if body != None:
                    self.send_header("Content-Type", type);
                    self.end_headers();
                    self.wfile.write(body.encode())

        def findFile(self, filepath):
            if os.path.exists(filepath):
                if os.path.isdir(filepath):
                    filepath += "/" + self.server.index
                    if os.path.exists(filepath):
                        return filepath
                else:
                    return filepath
            return None


        def serveFile(self, relativePath):
            if self.server.docroot != None:
                path = self.findFile(self.server.docroot + "/" + relativePath)
                if path == None:
                    path = self.findFile("./" + relativePath)

            else:
                path = self.findFile("./" + relativePath)                
                if path == None:
                    path = self.findFile(WEBIOPI_DOCROOT + "/" + relativePath)

            if path == None and (relativePath.startswith("webiopi.") or relativePath.startswith("jquery")):
                path = self.findFile(WEBIOPI_DOCROOT + "/" + relativePath)

            if path == None:
                return self.sendResponse(404, "Not Found")

            realPath = os.path.realpath(path)

            if realPath.endswith(".py"):
                return self.sendResponse(403, "Not Authorized")

            if not (realPath.startswith(os.getcwd()) 
                    or (self.server.docroot and realPath.startswith(self.server.docroot))
                    or realPath.startswith(WEBIOPI_DOCROOT)):
                return self.sendResponse(403, "Not Authorized")

            (type, encoding) = mime.guess_type(path)
            f = codecs.open(path, encoding=encoding)
            data = f.read()
            f.close()
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-Type", type);
            self.send_header("Content-Length", os.path.getsize(realPath))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(data)

        def processRequest(self):
            self.request.settimeout(None)
            if not self.checkAuthentication():
                return self.requestAuthentication()

            request = self.path.replace(self.server.context, "/").split('?')
            relativePath = request[0]
            if relativePath[0] == "/":
                relativePath = relativePath[1:]

            if relativePath == "webiopi" or relativePath == "webiopi/":
                self.send_response(301)
                self.send_header("Location", "/")
                self.end_headers()
                return

            params = {}
            if len(request) > 1:
                for s in request[1].split('&'):
                    if s.find('=') > 0:
                        (name, value) = s.split('=')
                        params[name] = value
                    else:
                        params[s] = None

            compact = False
            if 'compact' in params:
                compact = str2bool(params['compact'])

            try:
                result = (None, None, None)
                if self.command == "GET":
                    result = self.server.handler.do_GET(relativePath, compact)
                elif self.command == "POST":
                    length = 0
                    length_header = 'content-length'
                    if length_header in self.headers:
                        length = int(self.headers[length_header])
                    result = self.server.handler.do_POST(relativePath, self.rfile.read(length), compact)
                else:
                    result = (405, None, None)

                (code, body, type) = result

                if code > 0:
                    self.sendResponse(code, body, type)
                else:
                    if self.command == "GET":
                        self.serveFile(relativePath)
                    else:
                        self.sendResponse(404)

            except (GPIO.InvalidDirectionException, GPIO.InvalidChannelException, GPIO.SetupException) as e:
                self.sendResponse(403, "%s" % e)
            except ValueError as e:
                self.sendResponse(403, "%s" % e)
            except Exception as e:
                self.sendResponse(500)
                raise e


        def do_OPTIONS(self):
            self.sendResponse(200)
            self.processRequest()

        def do_GET(self):
            self.processRequest()

        def do_POST(self):
            self.processRequest()
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is raised because you don't have a `do_OPTIONS` method on your `HTTPHandler`. It will handle `OPTIONS` requests. I suspect you're going to have further problems, but that's a good start ;)

Comment: Hi @morphyn, i read about that before but I stuck while adding the do_OPTIONS method in the HTTPHandler. I thought about adding sth. like    def do_OPTIONS(self):           
        self.send_response(200, "ok")       
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')                
        self.send_header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS')
        self.send_header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With") inside      class HTTPHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler): but it doesn't work.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what does it mean ? Does the error message change ?

Comment: Also, do you have a reason not to use a tool like `Werkzeug` to facilitate this kind of work ?

Comment: sorry for beeing so unprecise (i usually don't like such behavior but sometimes I catch myself doing it...) "doesn't work" means in my case that the server stop working and didn't give any response. Iam usually not working with python so I dont have so much informations about debugging, yet. As i've seen Werkzeug wont work for me because I have to use python 3.2 and werkzeug is supporting up to 2.7. Do the do_OPTIONS method have to be called before the basic authentification or after it?

Comment: Well if it stops working you should have an error message in your console. Right ? Your code is quite long and convoluted and I'm having a hard time debugging it by just reading it ;)

Comment: I can understand that its not easy to debug in such a way. I know that from debugging Javascript. Unfortunately I have no access to a error log (yet?). Iam connected to a linux machine (raspi) via a terminal ssh session. The file is part of a framework (webiopi) and will be started via the framework. (so i have no idea how to see log messages)

Comment: thank's for your help, i got it working. I've changed my code editor and it was working well. May there were some problems with with that.